# Transition between routes in react-router-dom v6.3

Tags: html, reactjs, react-router-dom, framer-motion

So I´m currently refactoring a website, and so I do with the rrd, which was on v5 in the previous website version.
Now, that the  component doesn´t exist anymore we have to work with the new  component as you probably know.

I previously used framer-motion to transition in and out between the routes like so:

```
<Switch location={location} key={location.pathname}>
  <motion.div
    initial="initial"
    animate="in"
    exit="out"
    variants={pageVariants}
    transition={pageTransition}>
    <Route path="/audit" component={Audit} />
    <Route exact path="/smartx" component={SmartX} />
    <Route path="/smartx/erc20" component={TokenGenerator} />
    <Route path="/createAudit" component={PaymentStatus} />
    <Route path="/faq" component={FAQ} />
    <Route path="/support" component={Support} />
    <Route path="/terms" component={Terms} />
    <Route path="/policy" component={Policy} />
    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    <Route exact path="/">
      <Redirect to="/audit" />
    </Route>
  </motion.div>
</Switch>;
```

Simply replacing the Switch component with the Routes component won´t work, since you can only have Route components as childs from .
Moving the <motion.div> one layer up over the Routes component leads to only one initial fade in transition on page load.

new (not quiet working version):

```
<AnimatePresence>
  <PageLayout>
    <motion.div
      initial="initial"
      animate="in"
      variants={pageVariants}
      transition={pageTransition}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/audit" element={<Audit />} />
        <Route path="/smartx" element={<SmartX />} />
        <Route path="/faq" element={<FAQ />} />
        <Route path="/support" element={<Support />} />
        <Route path="/terms" element={<Terms />} />
        <Route path="/policy" element={<Policy />} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
      </Routes>
    </motion.div>
  </PageLayout>
</AnimatePresence>;
```

Framer motion animations (equalin both old and new version):

```
  const pageVariants = {
    initial: {
      opacity: 0
    },
    in: {
      opacity: 1
    },
    out: {
      opacity: 0
    }
  };

  const pageTransition = {
    type: 'tween',
    ease: 'linear',
    duration: 0.5
  };
```

Any ideas on how to achieve a transition on each route switch?

Comment: I guess you have to wait for framer-motion to push a patch to comply with react-router v6 breaking changes. I use react-spring useTransition to animate routing mount, I think that should work indipendently of react-router version since the animating on mount is done inside the component and not at Switch/Routes level.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think your solution is close to working. Move the `PageLayout` component and `motion.div` into a layout route that uses the current path as a React key.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const AnimationLayout = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  return (
    <PageLayout>
      <motion.div
        key={pathname}
        initial="initial"
        animate="in"
        variants={pageVariants}
        transition={pageTransition}
      >
        <Outlet />
      </motion.div>
    </PageLayout>
  );
};
```

...

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<AnimationLayout />}>
    <Route path="/audit" element={<Audit />} />
    <Route path="/smartx" element={<SmartX />} />
    <Route path="/faq" element={<FAQ />} />
    <Route path="/support" element={<Support />} />
    <Route path="/terms" element={<Terms />} />
    <Route path="/policy" element={<Policy />} />
    <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
    <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/audit" replace />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

[image: Edit transition-between-routes-in-react-router-dom-v6-3]

Comment: You my man, are an ab-so-lute genius! Worked out right away, thanks you so much!