# React-Router different animation for each route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, css-transitions

I'm struggling to make React-Router work well with CSSTransition, which seems to be the defacto library for this around the web.

I'm using React-Router v6 without any issue. I'm not sure if the issue is due to that or not being that it is more recent.

## Goal

My goal is to animate between my different route with an animation that plays when clicked-in and another that plays when clicked-out.

In term of style, I'm just looking at a simple "Slide-in" animation. Where my first component will slide-in-from-bottom and slide-out-to-bottom before the second component will slide-in-from-right and eventually slide-out-to-right when clicked out. and things like that.

## Issues

I can't believe this is so hard to put into practice. I am definitely not the first one that wants to do this.

I'm open to any suggestion that'll work and that uses React-Router.

- I have tried to use CSStransition in every way possible so far.
- I tried without it and tried making a new functional component that takes in "Location" and "PreviousLocation"(Custom State) in combination with useEffect to animate the div around the route before it is rendered but was way over my head and couldn't make it happen. Not sure how to prevent rendering while keeping what's already rendered and wait for the animation to finish to allow the render.

I would gladly take any help and any method that works at this point.

thanks.

My bare code just for reference (I have discarded everything I've tried and started fresh):

```
const App = () => {
    const location = useLocation();

    return (
        <div className="app">
            <section className="main">
                <Routes>
                    <Route index element={<Home />} />
                    <Route path="home" element={<Home />} />
                    <Route path="marketplace" element={<Marketplace />} >
                        <Route index element={<Listing />} />
                        <Route path="listing" element={<Listing />} />
                        <Route path="cart" element={<Cart />} />
                    </Route>
                </Routes>
            </section>
            <nav className="main-nav">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <NavLink to="/home" className={(navdata) => (navdata.isActive ? 'active' : 'none')} >
                            <span className="nav-text">Home</span>
                        </NavLink>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <NavLink to="/marketplace" className={(navdata) => (navdata.isActive ? 'active' : 'none')} >
                            <span className="nav-text">Store</span>
                        </NavLink>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <NavLink to="/aboutus" className={(navdata) => (navdata.isActive ? 'active' : 'none')} >
                            <span className="nav-text">About Us</span>
                        </NavLink>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <NavLink to="/user" className={(navdata) => (navdata.isActive ? 'active' : 'none')} >
                            <span className="nav-text">My Account</span>
                        </NavLink>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: I just answered a similar question a few days ago. Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71812613/8690857

Comment: @DrewReese I just checked your answer. I'm not familiar with this library but the behavior end up being the same animation for all of them. My goal is really to change the animation depending on the route taken. I see the "Variants", which seems to be what determine the animation but how can we change that after a route change? Meaning if the route isn't the same, it play the "out" animation for the current route, load up the in for the new route and play it.

Comment: I'm admittedly not super familiar with the framer motion library either, but more or less provided a link to an answer where animating `react-router-dom` route transitions *was* working. It would trivial to create a wrapper that renders the `children` prop instead of an `Outlet` to wrap individual routes. This is in fact the first version of the answer I provided before I got the layout route version working.

Answer (score 1):

The key part of a solution to creating transitions between routes is *dealing with exit transitions*, and **making sure the old route doesn't disappear instantly** so we have time to see the exit. By **passing a function** as the child of `Route`, we are able to achieve that.

To achieve a unique transition on each `Route` we simply need to provide each `Route` with it's own `CSSTransition` and set up the css properties for each transition.

A single `Route` would look like this:

```
<Route path="/user">
  {({ match }) => (
    <CSSTransition
      in={match != null}
      classNames="spin"
      timeout={500}
      unmountOnExit
    >
      <div className="absolute">
        <Marketplace />
      </div>
    </CSSTransition>
  )}
</Route>
```

And here is [a full example](https://codesandbox.io/s/transitions-between-routes-hd7kvy?file=/src/App.js) set up in codesandbox with four example of routes with unique transitions. They are not very pleasing animations, but are designed to show the concept clearly.

[image: Edit Transitions Between Routes]

[This page](http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/with-react-router/) has some great info about how to do this and what potential issues to watch out for, such as the need to use `absolute` or `fixed` positioning:

> Exit transitions will cause the content of routes to linger until they disappear, which might pose some styling challenges. Make sure that routes don't affect each other's layout, for example you can remove them from the flow of the document by using absolute or fixed positioning.

Comment: How do you make that work in v6? I can see your sandbox is using old version of both react router and CSSTransition. v6 doesn't allow children to be anything other than other route for nesting.

Comment: Those are the same versions used in all of the documentation for `react-transition-group` unfortunately. I'm going to take a look at the [React Router guide](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5) for switching to v6 and see if it has any helpful information